# Can't automatic resize youtube player according to device

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, resize

i'm new in html, css, js etc. im trying to resize a youtube window automatically to fit the screen of the device but it doesnt work for me.
I have tried many solutions given in this website and nothing seems to work.
Here is the part of the code for the video

HTML

```
 <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="h-iframe">
           <iframe  class="center-block" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Npa-z3P1FTY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```css
.h_iframe iframe {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%; 
  height:100%;
}

.center-block {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 }

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I use.

```css
/* Flexible iFrame */

.flexible-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.flexible-container iframe,
.flexible-container object,
.flexible-container embed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Responsive iFrame -->
<div class="flexible-container">
<iframe src="https://b922bde52f23a8481830-83cb7d8d544f653b52d1a1621f05ea9d.ssl.cf3.rackcdn.com/video/landingpage.mp4" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
</div>
```

[live link](https://jsfiddle.net/mlegg10/4t0jgeoj/)

Comment: Thanks, finally something that worked, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wqbbb7oa/1/)

You don´t need to call .h_iframe iframe and then, below, call .center_block (Which is the name of the class in your iframe) and also:

```
iframe{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Even though the previous answer worked, I also tried yours because it looked like a shorter approach to the problem, but it didn't work for what i was intending. Thank you anyways!

Comment: Yeah, there are a lot of purposes and different things to get it but i'm glad you found the right one.